# Shuffling algorithm analysis

Tags: algorithm

I came across this following analysis of shuffling algorithms:

> Q: Given an array of distinct integers, give an algorithm to randomly
> reorder the integers so that each possible reordering is equally
> likely. In other words, given a deck of cards, how can you shuffle
> them such that any permutation of cards is equally likely?
>
> Good answer: Go through the elements in order, swapping each element with a
> random element in the array that does not appear earlier than the
> element. This takes O(n) time. Note that there are several possible
> solutions to this problem, as well as several good‐looking answers
> that are incorrect. For example, a slight modification to the above
> algorithm whereby one switches each element with any element in the
> array **does not give each reordering with equally probability**.

What I would like to know is why switching each element with any other element in the array does not produce a good shuffle as opposed to using the Knuth shuffle (which is described). Also, how does the Knuth shuffle select values with equal probability? Any math or proof is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The easiest proof that this algorithm does not produce a uniformly random permutation

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
   swap(a[i], a[rand() % 3]);
}
```

Is that it generates 27 possible outcomes, but there are only 3! = 6 permutations.  Since 6 does not divide 27, there must be some permutation is that is picked too much, and some that is picked to little.

Why is an O(n) algorithm optimal?  Well, a random shuffle must touch every input sometimes (to change them), so any optimal algorithm needs to do at least O(n) work.

Why is the Knuth algorithm correct?  That requires a little bit more insight.  You can prove via induction that the first item is selected with the correct probability (each item is equally likely to be first), and then prove that the inductive step holds as you advance through the loop, that the second, third, etc items are also selected with the correct probability from the remaining portions of the array.

Comment: hey thanks for your answer. by optimal, i meant- how come the Knuth shuffle gives an equal probability for every element picked?

Comment: Wouldn't switching with **any** element in the array be: `swap(a[i], a[rand() % 3]);`?

Comment: One thing I love about the Knuth shuffle is how intuitively correct it is. Think of the shuffled part of the array (initially nothing) as a stack of cards, and the not-yet-shuffled part as a pile of cards. At each step, you pick one card at random from the pile and add it to the top of the stack. It's intuitively obvious that there's only one way to get a given ordering doing this, and that all orderings are equally likely.

Comment: sorry to be silly, could you explain a little bit how the op's algorithm generates 27 outcomes? I do not get it, @Mankarse 's answer is my logic process to evaluate why this algorithm is not equal, but your reasoning seems more straight, could you help explain.

Comment: @javarookie: The algorithm iterates three times, in each of those three times, the code picks one of three options at random. This is 3^3, or 27 different possible code paths.

Comment: just figure it out, seconds ago, @Mankarse, you rock!

Answer (score 6):

Consider a three element list. It has these possible states and associated probabilities:

```
1 [a, b, c] (0)
```

In the first shuffling operation, a has a 1/3 chance of being swapped with any of the elements, so the possible states and associated probabilities are as follows:

```
From (0)
1/3 [a, b, c] (1)
1/3 [b, a, c] (2)
1/3 [c, b, a] (3)
```

In the second shuffling operation, the same thing happens again except to the second slot, so:

```
From (1) ([a, b, c])
1/9 [b, a, c] (4)
1/9 [a, b, c] (5)
1/9 [a, c, b] (6)
From (2) ([b, a, c])
1/9 [a, b, c] (7)
1/9 [b, a, c] (8) 
1/9 [b, c, a] (9)
From (3) ([c, b, a])
1/9 [b, c, a] (10)
1/9 [c, b, a] (11)
1/9 [c, a, b] (12)
```

In the third shuffling operation, the same thing happens, except to the third slot, so:

```
From (4) ([b, a, c])
1/27 [c, a, b] (13)
1/27 [b, c, a] (14)
1/27 [b, a, c] (15)
From (5) ([a, b, c])
1/27 [c, b, a] (16)
1/27 [a, c, b] (17)
1/27 [a, b, c] (18)
From (6) ([a, c, b])
1/27 [b, c, a] (19)
1/27 [a, b, c] (20)
1/27 [a, c, b] (21)
From (7) ([a, b, c])    
1/27 [c, b, a] (22)
1/27 [a, c, b] (23)
1/27 [a, b, c] (24)
From (8) ([b, a, c])
1/27 [c, a, b] (25)
1/27 [b, c, a] (26)
1/27 [b, a, c] (27)
From (9) ([b, c, a])
1/27 [a, c, b] (28)
1/27 [b, a, c] (29)
1/27 [b, c, a] (30)
From (10) ([b, c, a])
1/27 [a, c, b] (31)
1/27 [b, a, c] (32)
1/27 [b, c, a] (33)
From (11) ([c, b, a])
1/27 [a, b, c] (34)
1/27 [c, a, b] (35)
1/27 [c, b, a] (36)
From (12) ([c, a, b])
1/27 [b, a, c] (37)
1/27 [c, b, a] (38)
1/27 [c, a, b] (39)
```

Combining the like terms, we get:

```
4/27 [a, b, c] From (18), (20), (24), (34)
5/27 [a, c, b] From (17), (21), (23), (28), (31)
5/27 [b, a, c] From (15), (27), (29), (32), (37)
5/27 [b, c, a] From (14), (19), (26), (30), (33)
4/27 [c, a, b] From (13), (25), (35), (39)
4/27 [c, b, a] From (16), (22), (36), (38)
```

This is clearly uneven.

The shuffle where you only select from elements that have not already been selected is correct. For proof I present this:

Consider you have a bag of elements. If you randomly pick from that bag and place the resulting elements in a list, you will get a randomly ordered list. This is essentially what swapping with only those elements that have not yet been selected does (Consider the list in which you place stuff to be the start of the list, and the bag to be the tail of the list which can be swapped with).

Answer (score 3):

First, it's not *quite* true that the described algorithm is O(n), although it's pretty close. It should really be O(n*log(n)).

Here's why: the first swap requires drawing from n elements, then n-1 ... 2. But the complexity of selecting from n elements should really be log(n), because you have to generate log(n) random bits.

rrenaud gives a nice argument that the "bad" algorithm isn't uniform, so I'll try and argue that the "good" algorithm is uniform. Each step you pick one out of n, n-1, ... 1 choices, so there are ultimately a total of n! choices you could make. Since there are n! ways to arrange a list, if every arrangement can be reached by at least one sequence of choices, then every arrangement can be reached by exactly one sequence of choices. Thus to show that it is uniform we only need to show that given some possible ordering, we can reach it by a sequence of choices.

Now the problem looks straightforward. Say you start with

> a b c d e

And you want to get

> b c d e a

Put your cursor on the 0th element. Which should you swap with? b, because you want to move it to the 0 position. Now progress. At each step, all the elements "behind" you are in the right spot, so when you get to the end, all the elements are in the right spot.

Comment: thanks owen. unfortunately, i disagree with your first statement. the algorithm is O(n) because the complexity of selecting from n elements is O(1) since you rely on the contiguous form of the array to select a random element within the array index range. assuming that the random number generator generates a number at O(1), the algorithms runs at O(n).
another point: "Since there are n! ways to sort a list" should actually be "Since there are n! ways to permute a list". there is a big difference between what you said and what you meant. but again, thanks for your help.

Comment: @OckhamsRazor If you need to select from n elements, you need at least log2(n) random bits to make that decision.

Comment: The problem Owen has is that generating a random number is _not_ O(1).  For example some implementations of `rand()` have a `RAND_MAX` of 32K.   (16bits.) Thus if you want to shuffle between 2^16 and 2^32 items you'll need 2 calls to rand, and progressively more as the number grows. (It's even more tricky if you need to ensure that the results are truely unbiased due to mod clipping :( but you may be happy to ignore that bias. )

Comment: so random number generation does not run at O(1)? okay, then owen might be right. also, you mentioned "at least one sequence of choices". while i get what you mean, the wording is misleading. if there are x sequences to get to an ordering, this must be true for all orderings in order to qualify the distribution as even. your wording implies that getting to some ordering only has to have a minimum of 1 sequence and it doesn't matter if getting to some other ordering has a lot more ways to get there. otherwise, i do like your answer.

Comment: @OckhamsRazor That's a good point, I was a little unclear. What I meant was that since there are n! choices and n! orderings, if every ordering has at least one choice, then every ordering has exactly one choice. If you can suggest a rewording I'll edit it.

Comment: cool, i like your comment. also, i would replace the word "sort" with "arrange" in "n! ways to sort a list". +1

Comment: @Michael if we use java's random number generator, the generation of numbers is O(1).

Comment: @OckhamsRazor:from http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html `The algorithms implemented by class Random use a protected utility method that on each invocation can supply up to 32 pseudorandomly generated bits.` - This means you need two calls if you want to shuffle more than 2^32 etc. . unlikely but technically not O(1).

Comment: i see. how does that become log(n) though (as owen mentioned)?

Comment: @OckhamsRazor Say you wanted to draw from 2^64 elements -- you'd need to make 2 calls to randInt, if there were 2^96 elements 3 calls, and so on.

Comment: thats O(n) though. each time you add 2^32, you make 1 call. thats linear isn't it?

Comment: @OkhamsRazor Correct it is linear in the number of bits, or `O(log(n))` in the number of elements. But that `log(n)` gets applied each time you make a random choice, and there are `n` random choices, so it becomes `n*log(n)` (Techncally that would be `log(n) + log(n-1) + ... + log(1) = log(n!)` but that is asymptotically the same as `n*log(n)`)

Answer (score 1):

First off, note that Knuth's way must be uniformly random, since this is essentially equivalent to drawing random cards from stack A and forming stack B by laying these down in the random order. That has to be uniformly random.

To see that the other way is bad, it suffices to show that the number of distinct outcomes precludes there being a uniform result. There are 52^52 ways to pick 52 random integers between 1 and 52. However, there are 52! permutations of these integers. 52! has 47 as a factor, whereas 52^52 does not; so 52! Does not evenly divide 52^52. this means that at least one permutation has more outcomes that lead to it than some other permutation... to see this, try evenly dividing outcomes until you run out. Since the number of outcomes isn't a multiple of the number of permutations, you cannot give everybody the same amount. In other words, you can't evenly divide 12 suckers to 5 kids, if you give away all the suckers. Same principle.