# How stdrandom shuffle method works

Tags: java, sorting, shuffle

```
 public static void shuffle(Object[] a) {
    int N = a.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            int r = StdRandom.uniform(i + 1);      
            exchange( a, i , r) 
        }
    }
```

above is a method from StdRandom Class coded in java. I was wondering why for stdRandom.uniform( i + 1) it is between 0 and i and not between 0 and (N - 1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short  answer is that between 0 and N-1 does not create a uniformly random distribution.

When designing a shuffle, you want to make sure that all possible random combinations of value placement are equally likely, and the 0 to N-1 makes some outcomes more likely than others.

For a more detailed discussion, see [Shuffling algorithm analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7291457/shuffling-algorithm-analysis).

Answer (score 2):

The shuffle algorithm works just as you would if you were shuffling cards with a hat. Throw all the cards loosely into the hat.  Draw out a random card and place it in position 0, then another and place it at position 1, etc. until the hat is empty and all the places are filled.

In the algorithm when  `i` is being filled, *the rest of the array* (positions i+1, i+2, ... N-1) is the hat.  The `exchange` is pulling a random item out of that hat and placing it where it needs to be.  The item that *was* at position `i` is moved upward so that it's still in the hat.  Where it lies in the hat is unimportant because the next random number will pick all hat positions with equal probability.

Hope this intuitive explanation makes sense...